# How to start a task at same time in different android phones?

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am trying to build a Metronome app for my college project. In this app I have to start a timer in different android phones at exactly same time, when the timer finishes I am playing a pre-downloaded song. The way I approached this problem is I am using Parse.com to send push notification to devices. In that push I am sending a duration after which every device will start the countdown.

Now the problem is delay in sending and receiving push. There is very small time difference in the duration of when push is sent and when each device is receiving the push. This delay is not same for every device. Due to this the audio played on each device is not exactly in sync.

A small [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BY2qqCS2rdY) of what I have done so far.

If you see the video you must have heard two knocking sound when timer ends. This is because of that inconsistent delay in push.

Can anyone please suggest me any way of getting more accurate synchronization on each device?

Comment: Perhaps subscribing to a mqtt topic from all three devices and have the master signal the start ?

Comment: Parse is not made for real time. You should check Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Timing a metronome perfectly will be difficult because since sound is so slow it will literally be off if the device is a couple feet away. As a test you can take two synced ticking clocks or metronomes and put them even 4 feet apart and you will hear the difference.

Have you tried tying it to the clock? Like, after it gets the push to start the metronome at the beginning of a new second?

Take a look at `System.nanoTime()`:
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()

It sounds like a cool project.